# Spark: Reading files using different delimiter than new line

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark 1.0.1. I have many files delimited with UTF8 `\u0001` and not with the usual new line `\n`. How can I read such files in Spark? Meaning, the default delimiter of `sc.textfile("hdfs:///myproject/*")` is `\n`, and I want to change it to `\u0001`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spark shell, I extracted data according to [Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692857/setting-textinputformat-record-delimiter-in-spark):

```
$ spark-shell
...
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

scala> val conf = new Configuration
conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml

scala> conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\u0001")

scala> val data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("mydata.txt", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf).map(_._2.toString)
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)] = NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopFile at <console>:19
```

`sc.newAPIHadoopFile("mydata.txt", ...)` is a `RDD[(LongWritable, Text)]`, where the first part of the elements is the starting character index, and the second part is the actual text delimited by `"\u0001"`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `textinputformat.record.delimiter` to set the delimiter for `TextInputFormat`, E.g.,

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "X")
val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("file_path", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
val lines = input.map { case (_, text) => text.toString}
println(lines.collect)
```

For example, my input is a file containing one line `aXbXcXd`. The above code will output

```
Array(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: When I run above codes in spark-shell, I got the following errors:

    scala> val job = new Job(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:283)

How to fix this "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING" problem?

Comment: Could you paste the full stack track in some place and provide a link?

Answer (score 7):

In python this could be achieved using:

```
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(YOUR_FILE, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat",
            "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
            conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": YOUR_DELIMITER}).map(lambda l:l[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ready-to-use version of [Chad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162624/9297144)'s and [@zsxwing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25262706/9297144)'s answers for Scala users, which can be used this way:

```scala
sc.textFile("some/path.txt", "\u0001")
```

The following snippet creates an additional `textFile` method implicitly attached to the `SparkContext` using an `implicit class` (in order to replicate `SparkContext`'s default `textFile` method):

```scala
package com.whatever

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

object Spark {

  implicit class ContextExtensions(val sc: SparkContext) extends AnyVal {

    def textFile(
        path: String,
        delimiter: String,
        maxRecordLength: String = "1000000"
    ): RDD[String] = {

      val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

      // This configuration sets the record delimiter:
      conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", delimiter)
      // and this one limits the size of one record:
      conf.set("mapreduce.input.linerecordreader.line.maxlength", maxRecordLength)

      sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
          path,
          classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],
          conf
        )
        .map { case (_, text) => text.toString }
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used this way:

```scala
import com.whatever.Spark.ContextExtensions
sc.textFile("some/path.txt", "\u0001")
```

---

Note the additional setting `mapreduce.input.linerecordreader.line.maxlength` which limits the maximum size of a record. This comes in handy when reading from a corrupted file for which a record could be too long to fit in memory (more chances of it happening when playing with the record delimiter).

With this setting, when reading a corrupted file, an exception (`java.io.IOException` - thus catchable) will be thrown rather than getting a messy out of memory which will stop the SparkContext.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spark-context, the below code helped me
`sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","delimeter")`

Comment: if Spark >= 2.0, use `spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","delimeter")`