# Split a large text file on a delimiter using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have text file where entries (log events) are not split by new lines. Unfortunately everything is over a single line:

> Info|[Log] iffidfdfdfdfdfd
> testst ddedede dede  dedededed
> warning|[Log] etststs dedessdsds
> trtrtrtrtrtrtrtr
> Error| [Log]  tetdtetdetddeded
> dededededededed    dedededededededede

My goal is to split this one huge line into different lines per log event:

> Info|[Log] iffidfdfdfdfdfd testst ddedede dede  dedededed
>
> warning|[Log] etststs dedessdsds trtrtrtrtrtrtrtr
>
> Error| [Log] tetdtetdetddeded dededededededed dedededededededede

Comment: If your file is stored in hdfs, this one might [help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25259425/1553233)