# In Apache Spark CSV we are giving the delimiter for field but how to give delimiter for row?

Tags: apache-spark

we have different types of CSV files some of them are new line character for row delimiter and some of them are other custom separators like |,!..etc are row delimiter. So how to supply row delimiter in spark CSV data reading.

Answer (score -2):

In Spark 2.0 you can pass the delimiter as an option.
Example:

```
var options = new HashMap[String, String]()
options += ("header" -> "true")
options += ("delimiter" -> "\t")
options += ("maxCharsPerColumn" -> "200")
```

You can then pass the options and read the csv:         spark.read.format("csv").options(options).load("fileLocation")

Comment: I used same 
Dataset<Row> csvDs = spark.read().format("CSV").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load(model.getFilePath());
Here the code works fine the with field delimiter as and by default row delimiter as new line("\n").
My Question is here we have only delimiter which is for field delimiter  i am asking about row delimiter for example the data file like this 
ID,Name|1,Srinu|2,Srinu Babu

here the row delimiter is |

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259425/spark-reading-files-using-different-delimiter-than-new-line